# Using property name in plural instead of its units

Tags: word-usage, measuring-units

Consider describing an object and referring to some of its properties, that has a unit (eg. weight in kilograms). Is it correct to describe the property not by saying what unit is it in, but using just the name of this property?

As in

> This car has five hundred torques

instead of

> This car has five hundred pound-feet of torque

I hear it quite a lot, watching TopGear and on the internet. Is it common and/or correct to omit the unit? Or is it only used when talking about car-related properties?

Comment: Don't try to learn grammar from Top Gear. "Five hundred torques" doesn't actually make any sense without the units - it's a jokey way of talking, as if by someone who doesn't know what torque is, but thinks the figures sound impressive.

Comment: @SimonB That's just what I thought - that it's only colloquial, a kind of an insider joke. I just wondered if it's only TopGear specific or is it used anywhere else.
By the way, personally I really don't like it when someone omits the units - especially if it's in the documentation of an application you should write.

Comment: If you misinterpret the units, it's the difference between a Jaguar XKR and a Jaguar XJR. OK, perhaps with cars' performance it's only a small issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the rather cumbersome names of [the units proper for *torque*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque#Units), it is to be expected that in contexts where torque must be specified often, some short-cuts will creep into at least oral usage. Unfortunately [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=torques_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) cannot readily measure this usage, as *torque* may also be used as a count noun, with a plural, in comparisons of different degrees of torque or even in reference to iron-age jewelry. Informal specifications of a person’s height (since another answerer brought this up by way of analogy) work somewhat differently: we will hear a person’s height specified as “six-two” or “five feet,” with the word “height” elided in both cases, and all units elided too in the first. Torque is a less intuitively obvious and commonplace concept than height, so that approach would not work so well for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question in mathematics and logic, not of language. This question can be asked in any language, be it Cantonese, Russian, Indonesian, Hindi, etc.

*Torque* is used here as a state. It is not even a unit. *pound-feet* is the unit.

You are like asking

- Can I say *He is five heights* instead of *He is five feet in height* ?

Please think in your own native/proficient language and see if your question is at all logical in the first place.

- This is a four bedroom house.
- He has been mad for five days.

vs

- This is a four houses.
- He is five mads.

???

Comment: But language usage does shift. _This is three sizes too small._

Comment: The scholarship and academia of Physics and Mathematics will never allow such ideas to slip and fall. It has been so for the last 1000 years and will not for the next 1000 years. What more, in the reality of today?

Comment: But, but, but ... wait a minute, *size* is a graduated unit, like *step*, *level*, *standard*. e.g., *That student of form five has a sibling in standard five.* *Torque*, *weight*, *height* are not graduated units.

Comment: I'm assuming Shakespeare wouldn't have been aware of the graduated unit usage. 'This doublet is several sizes too big.' As I say, language usage does shift.

Comment: As I expressed, "size" is a graduated unit. Why are you beating a dead horse?

Comment: The fact that you boldly proclaim 'This is a question in mathematics and logic, not of language.' 'Horses' has been used as a synonym of 'horsepower'. And Clarkson has harnessed 'torques' as a putative synonym of , I assume, ' ‎Newton metres'. How acceptable either is in everyday language is a question about English.

Comment: +Edwin, you are arguing the reverse case.

Comment: So why say I'm beating a dead horse? I don't think many would support your view that word usage isn't a question of language.

Comment: Because reverse, the turning of quantitative term into a qualitative term is what people do. But using a qualitative term which has 5 different quantitative means, as a quantitative term is mathematically illogical because you will not know which of the quantitative measure is to be implied. So this question is the domain of mathematics, where the mathematics would explain exactly what I have just explained.

Comment: If you really believed that, you would be hypocritical to answer rather than to close-vote.

Comment: Sometimes I would not mind being a *hippocrete*, if it helps to get my message across. Also, I am among the least down-voting, trigger-happy-closing user here.